# The way to keep the alert display when viewing the production web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a program to keep the alert display when viewing the production web page.

For example, I have two pages as follows:

- TEST environment ) https://example.com/123
- PROD environment ) https://example.com/456

Only when viewing the PROD page, I'd like to display the alert that covers the content. Please see the image I attached.

[image]

As I'm beginner of programing, I have no idea how to realize it. Could anyone give me an advice for this? I have basic knowledges of HTML/CSS/Java/JS.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's define a function like this:

```js
function alertProd(url, prodPattern) {
    if (url.indexOf(prodPattern) >= 0) alert("PROD!");
}

alertProd(window.location.href, "stacksnippets");
```

Note that I have used `stacksnippets` as pattern, you will need to change it to `456` when you call the function.